# Don't want to record the network traffic in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

Presently, the loadrunner is recording browser actions as well as the network traffic. Is there a way to exclude the network traffic from recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is Runtime Settings -> Internet Protocol -> Download Filters

Answer (score 0):

Your post is confusing.  Are you suggesting that LoadRunner is recording and presenting in the resultant generated script/code the actions of multiple processes or users and not just the browser and its actions?

Comment: In Jmeter we can exclude the content that we don't want to record. I hope there should be a similar feature in loadrunner too.

Comment: Really, in 20 years I have never known LoadRunner to record other users and other processes.   This must be a defect in the release you are using because this would not be considered normal nor expected behavior.  I recommend contacting support with your support contract.

Comment: to your larger question of filtering content both recorded as well as content in the script but which you don't want to play back, such as requests to third party sites, Yes there are ways to set filters for both.   I would refer you to your VUGEN web virtual users training material, the online help and the users guide for information on recording and playback options

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to record network traffic in your script, try below flow in loadrunner

Recording Options ->  Port Mapping -> click on Options -> Disable the options at there.

then its never record the network traffic

Comment: The solution you proposed didn't work for me. When my web application gets opened during the recording process. The number of events that are recorded goes to more than 1000 (even though I do not make any action on the application). The events that are recorded are the downloading of the images, adding cookies etc.

Comment: if the recorded events are images and cookies means it's not network traffic, its web traffic only.but in the question you mentioned like network traffic.above what i mentioned is for network traffic only.

Comment: if u want to filter those events from recording then try this, Recording Option ->HTML Properties -> Advanced-> Content Types, check the options at there to exclude

Comment: ,your reply is helpful. By selecting 'Do not record non HTML generative elements...' I am able to record much less script. Though I am still recording urls like 'http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net' Is there a way to exclude them?